# android version upload is different with app in google play

Tags: android, google-play, android-signing

I uploaded my app in google developer console, my app is 29 Mg size and it's works very well, but problem is after publishing app when any user wants to download my app.they download a version that has 23 Mg 
This version has problem and they got error for example in any activities we have database app crashed

Do you know why it happen?

Comment: Probably because you uploaded the wrong apk

Comment: i am sure. i uploaded new version with new version code and version name

Comment: build your code again and upload your apk

Comment: i did.but it dosent changed, i dont know i happend for you?

Comment: i signed App with my sign key. if i use google sign it has different key ?

Comment: no please sign again with same key but different version so your same app will be updated

Comment: no .i mean everything is ok but when we uploaded apk in google play our dosent work carefully.